# What can I infer from Discriminator and Generator loss?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I have trained a GAN and when looking at the loss graphs ,what should I infer, if the discriminator is too strong ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this problem is known as discriminator's loss "collapse". Maybe adding more layers to generator or adding LeakyRelue activations and batch normalization helps. More details are provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313306/dcgans-discriminator-getting-too-strong-too-quickly-to-allow-generator-to-learn?rq=1).